# jquery two function use same array variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

two slide function, slide image array format not same ( one have src: text before ), i need two function use same variable so i dont want create two array, i dont know how to do, any simple way? here is the code

first slideshow function

```
    $('#slide').slideshow1({
      preload: true,
      timer: true,
      // alot of other setting

      // i need use variable here, ie. slide: slide_image_array
      slides: [
        {src: 'img/slide-image-01.jpg'},
        {src: 'img/slide-image-02.jpg'},
        {src: 'img/slide-image-03.jpg'}
      ]
    });
  }
```

another slideshow function

```
function slideshow2(){

  $.backstretch([
    // i need use same variable here, ie. slide_image_array
    'img/slide-image-01.jpg',
    'img/slide-image-02.jpg',
    'img/slide-image-03.jpg'
  ],
  {duration: 1000, fade: 800});

}
```

two question

1. how can use one variable 'slide_image_array' to store image set for two function?
2. in 'slide_image_array' array, how can have a variable to type number, ie. number is 8, then auto set slide-image-01.jpg - slide-image-08.jpg, use the each function? please give me some hints

thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable in a shared scope

```
var slides = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    slides.push({
        src: 'img/slide-image-' + (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i) + '.jpg'
    })
}

function slideshow1() {
    $('#slide').slideshow1({
        preload: true,
        timer: true,
        slides: slides
    });
}

function slideshow2() {

    $.backstretch($.map(slides, function () {
        return this.src;
    }), {
        duration: 1000,
        fade: 800
    });

}
```

Comment: awesome !!! work perfect, two more info i want to know, if store number in other js file, that file only have variable, no other code, ie. main js file (var i = 1; i <= number_variable; i++)..., in other js file var number_variable = 8, my method is it good or bad? please give me some suggest, and why slideshow2 work? array have text "src", why this method can filter "src" text on slideshow2, thank so much :)

Comment: @aboutjquery for the second query see the answer from guest271314

Comment: @aboutjquery if the `number_variable` is in another file that should be loaded first then the file with the loop code then the `slideshow1` functions

Comment: i try number_variable in another file, work :) in guest271314 answer, return {"src":val} for slideshow1, but in this answer edit before, use same variable 'slides' with no need return src, and work too ( i try yet), why this will work at slideshow2? thanks :)

Comment: @aboutjquery not sure how... not familiar with the said plugin

Comment: @aboutjquery I guess so

Comment: maybe the plugin can use src format, although i tried use same varable before ask this question but not work, i think is my code wrong, thanks :) this answer work perfect , nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var backstretch = [
    // i need use same variable here, ie. slide_image_array
    'img/slide-image-01.jpg',
    'img/slide-image-02.jpg',
    'img/slide-image-03.jpg'
    ];

var slideshow = backstretch.map(function(val) {
  return {"src":val}
});

$('#slide').slideshow1({
      preload: true,
      timer: true,
      // alot of other setting    
      // i need use variable here, ie. slide: slide_image_array
      slides: slideshow
});
// }

function slideshow2(){    
  $.backstretch(backstretch,
  {duration: 1000, fade: 800});  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put your code for handling images for your slider in a separate object:

```
var SliderImageStorage = {  

    create : function(index, imgTemplate) {
        toArray: function() {
            ...             
        },
        toSrcArray: (function(){
            ... 
        };
    }
}

var sliderImageStorage = SliderImageStorage.create(5, 'imgs/slide-image-{0}.jpg');
```